Ctags produces tags without parentheses after functions
Ctags produces a tags file without () after functions. As a result, Vim's Ctrl+] can't search for functions. How to fix this?
~/ $ cat example.hxx
bool function() {
    return true;
}
~/ $ ctags example.hxx
~/ $ cat tags | grep function
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C++      f,function      /function definitions/
function        example.hxx       /^bool function() {$/;" f       typeref:typename:bool
~/ $ vim -t "function()"
E426: Tag not found: function()
~/ $ ctags --fields=+l --extras=+q example.hxx
~/ $ cat tags | grep function
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C++      f,function      /function definitions/
function        example.hxx       /^bool function() {$/;" f       language:C++    typeref:typename:bool
~/ $ vim -t "function()"
E426: Tag not found: function()

All searches (+ Assistant) found were the options to add to ctags, which do not fix Vim use.
A possible solution is:
~/ $ sed "s/^\(\w\+\)\t/\1()\t/" -i"" tags
~/SubStack/tmp $ cat tags | grep function
!_TAG_KIND_DESCRIPTION!C++      f,function      /function definitions/
function()      example.hxx       /^bool function() {$/;" f       typeref:typename:bool
~/SubStack/tmp $ vim -t "function()"
example.hxx                                                                                                   4,0-1          All
"example.hxx" 4L, 35B

but this prevents such simple README.md instructions such as "Execute ctags -R . in the project root if you want Vim to jump to tags",
as does:
~/ $ echo "\"nnoremap <C-]> :let stripped = expand(\"<cword>\")<CR>:execute \"tag \" . substitute(stripped, '()', '', 'g')<CR> \"`Tag not found: function()` fix" >> ~/.vimrc

It appears that if you use ~/.vimrc:setlocal iskeyword you cannot use ./tags.
What to do?

how is that related to c++?

StackOverflow suggested the C++ tag. It is a C++ project, and the problem occurs with C++ files. The guidelines said to reduce the problem to the most short form you can, thus have reduced this to C99, but want a fix for C++ too. Assistant says that ctags can do both.

Why woulds you want to use vim -t "function()"? That's not how ctahs is supposed to be used. Just go with vim -t function like everyone else on this planet.

Starting a question with code is usually a bad idea. It's better to start with your question so that people know why they are reading code. (See [ask].)

What does :set iskeyword? print? You may have this option misconfigured which might make <C-]> pick up the trailing parentheses. See :help 'iskeyword' for a value that works with C.

@JaMiT Have not used vim -t much (with or without ()), but English is ambiguous, thus the original post includes the /bin/sh version of the problem, plus actual use (which is with vim, through <ctrl>+])

@Friedrich "autocmd FileType h,c,hpp,hxx,cpp,cxx setlocal iskeyword+=(,),{,},[,],<,= was the culprit. But without this, w skips whole function invocations (rather than tokens), thus "remove iskeyword config" does not solve.


As one of the prototypal high-context language, English is the opposite of ambiguous. 2. Yes, removing that silly autocommand will solve your self-inflicted tags problem. What w does or doesn't do with or without that autocommand is unrelated.


@romainl If the text at the start of the original post is not a question, what do you call this ("Ctags produces a tags file without () after functions. As a result, Vim's Ctrl+] can't search for functions. How to fix this?")? If there is an argument over the definition of common words such as "question", English is ambiguous.

@SwuduSusuwu "but English is ambiguous, thus the original post includes the /bin/sh version of the problem" -- I didn't say to get rid of the code block. Definitely keep it, but also describe what's going on in English.

Generally, prefer to [edit] your question rather than answering in comments. Additional information will be in the right spot and can quickly be found by future readers. Consider the suggestions made in comments. They were written by people who care enough about your question to try and help you improve it. Don't fight them.

As for the problem at hand, I'd consider leaving iskeyword at its default and instead mapping w (and its siblings) to do whatever you want it to do. Less collateral damage this way.

Oops. But must insist that English is ambiguous, or that English is not simple to use.

@SwuduSusuwu "But must insist that English is ambiguous" -- You keep repeating this, and yet it's not significant. Unexplained code is even more ambiguous. The best approach is to have both, starting with the English. The ambiguities in the English can be sorted out by the code, and the ambiguities in the code can be resolved by the text.

The root cause of the problem is adding parentheses to Vim's 'iskeyword' option.
This will not only cause the (intended) change of commands like w but will also make <C-]> pick up trailing parentheses for tag lookup.
Changing the behavior of ctags or post-processing the tags file serves only to work around the original problem.
Continue down this road and you'll have to compile your own ctags, only the compiler won't work so you need to change it as well, only it will not work on your OS so you need to change the kernel, only it doesn't run on your hardware so you need to build your own CPU ...
Jokes aside, just don't change 'iskeyword'.
There are some Vim options which I personally consider are "don't touch" options and 'iskeyword' is one of them.
In your comment, you mention that you want to make w go by token.
This has no meaning in Vim.
Vim is a text editor, and words are a very convenient and natural unit in text; both of natural language and programming language.
I'd strongly suggest to leave the w command as it is.
It's just too useful.
A token is something a compiler's parser would concern itself with.
There may be some kind of plugin which might have access to a source code's syntax tree and thus enable movement by token.
I wouldn't know such a plugin.
If you want to, you can create a buffer-local mapping.
I don't completely understand what you want to achieve but the following simple mapping may be a starting point:
:noremap <buffer> <leader>w /[)}]<CR>

Read :help mapping for the complete tour of mappings.
For consistency, you might also want to create mappings for the complete zoo of W, e, E, b, B, etc.
Although Vim does not care about tokens, chances are that it already offers a motion command that works for you.
I'm thinking of % which will jump to the next matching parenthesis.
See :help % and take a look at all of :help motion.txt.

As mentioned in the comments, the tag is function, not function().
Since you are searching for a non-existing tag, it is quite normal for your ctags client to answer something along the line of Tag not found: function(). You would have the same result if you searched for dksdfsdt.
So, the correct process is generally:

Generate the tags file at the root of your project with:
$ ctags -R .


Open Vim at tag foobar with:
$ vim -t foobar


Jump to the tag under your cursor with:
<C-]>


Etc.


No need for a fancy custom mapping or anything: it just works™.
In other words, everything is working correctly, here, except your expectations.

vim example.hxx, move the cursor over function, press ctrl+]; it gives the error E426: Tag not found: function()
The original post points out that you can use .vimrc to alter vim's default behaviour (so that it does not include () when you search for functions); this is not a solution for projects whose goal is to support contributors who use default vim.
Have not used vim -t, but English is ambiguous, thus the original post includes the /bin/sh version of the problem, plus actual use (which is with vim, through <ctrl>+])

Maybe with your setup, which you didn't share with us but certainly not in $ vim -Nu NONE or $ vim --clean or Vim with my config or… The desired behavior is the default behavior. @friedrich suggested 'iskeyword', did you check?
